# Why doesn't one of my two baseboard heaters produce heat?

Tags: electrical, heating

I have Federal Pacific baseboard heating in my bedroom. One will heat, the other one will not. The one that doesn’t heat has the control in it.  What might be the problem?

Also where is the thermostat in the baseboard heaters? The one that heats does not keep a temperature. Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked for a model number? That might be critical information.

Comment: I have not had any problems with federal Pacific heaters. I have seen quite a few thermostats go bad over the years. many times the stat was on the wall or a line voltage thermostat close to the entry or a light switch. Since the non working unit appears to have external control I would be looking for a line voltage thermostat or the possibility that the unit that is working with a thermostat is feeding the non working unit. I have seen a few baseboards heat element fail but not very many a voltage check is needed since they used to only open 1 leg need to know the voltage as most were 240v.

Comment: Just for reference, baseboard heaters cost about $50 and thermostats cost about $15.  One time I spent a half day trying to troubleshoot and save an electrical machine.  Only to later discover any electrical supply would sell me another one for $24.

Answer (score 0):

Turn power off and open the cover on the heater. The wire nut could have fallen off or there could be a short. I've had to wrap wires going to base heaters with electrical tape because the wires sometimes chafe the heater. The thermostat could also be bad or the wire could have been cut somewhere. You could test for voltage there and also do a continuity test to your panel with a cable tracker (or external thermostat) if you don't have voltage.